# Как обратиться к this класса из return в функции?

Tags: reactjs

Пытаюсь вывести в цикле список из стейта с радио-кнопкой рядом. Но не получается нацепить обработчик на эту кнопку.
Такой код:

```js
Class App extends Component {
  state = {
    option: 'option',
    points = ['goblin', 'puchkov', 'klim', 'sanich']
  
  };
  handleRadionButton(x) {
   this.setState({ option: x.target.value })
}
  
  render() {
    const point = this.state.points.map(function(item, index) {
        return(
           <ul>
             <li key={index}>{item}</li>
             <input onChange={this.handleRadioButton.bind(this)} value={'option' + index} type='radio'></input>

          </ul>


             )
         })
    return (
      <div>
        { point }
      </div>  
    
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

В итоге, при попытке обращения к this, оказывается, что оно === undefined. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, что не так? И как можно обратиться к state в return в функции?

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у вас 2 варианта:

сделать из функции handleRadionButton стрелочную функцию

```
handleRadionButton = () => {}
```

либо привязать в контекст например в конструкторе

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleRadionButton = this.handleRadionButton.bind(this)
}
```

вот [тут](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#how-do-i-bind-a-function-to-a-component-instance) можно почитать

Comment: В "почитать" нашёл ответ. Моё почтение.